# Deform a certain $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{G}(1,4)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^4$ a rational normal curve. Then the variety of secant lines in $\mathbb{G}(1,4)$ is isomorphic to the second symmetric product of $C$, hence a $\mathbb{P}^2$. Is there a small flat deformation of this $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{G}(1,4)$ to something that is not a variety of secant lines?

Comment: The morphism from $\mathbb{P}^2=\text{Sym}^2(C)$ to $\text{Grass}(1,\mathbb{P}^4)$ is unramified.  Thus we have a short exact sequence of locally free sheaves from the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$ to the pullback of the tangent bundle of $\text{Grass}(1,\mathbb{P}^4)$ to the "normal bundle."  By the long exact sequence of cohomology, the higher cohomology of the "normal bundle" vanishes.  So the Hilbert scheme parameterizing closed subschemes of $\text{Grass}(1,\mathbb{P}^4)$ is smooth at this point with dimension equal to the "expected dimension."

Comment: I don't know the notation that you are using. Please state which field your projective 4-space is defined over. Is your G(1,4) just another notation for P^3 (over the same field)? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielAsimov I work over the complex numbers and I am looking at the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}^4$. Anyways, I think I can work with what Jason Starr wrote (thanks Jason!)